# Replacing missing values & updating old values in a dataframe using Numpy and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to replace missing values reflected by '...' in my dataframe with `np.nan` values.
I also want to update some old values, but my method seems not working.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 


def func():
    energy=pd.ExcelFile('Energy Indicators.xls').parse('Energy')
    energy=energy.iloc[16:][['Environmental Indicators: Energy','Unnamed: 3','Unnamed: 4','Unnamed: 5']].copy()
    energy.columns=['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
    o="..."
    n=np.NaN

    # Trying to replace missing values with np.nan values 
    energy[energy['Energy Supply']==o]=n


    energy['Energy Supply']=energy['Energy Supply']*1000000


    # Here, I want to replace old values by new ones ==> Same problem 
    old=["Republic of Korea","United States of America","United Kingdom of " 
                                +"Great Britain and Northern Ireland","China, Hong "
                                +"Kong Special Administrative Region"]
    new=["South Korea","United States","United Kingdom","Hong Kong"]
    for i in range(0,4):


        energy[energy['Country']==old[i],'Country']=new[i]


    return energy
```

Here is the `.xls` file I'm working on: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80lepon1RrYeDRNQVFWYVVENHM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with regex based `df.replace`:

```
energy = energy.replace(r'\s*\.+\s*', np.nan, regex=True)
```

---

MaxU proposed an [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869116/replacing-missing-values-updating-old-values-in-a-dataframe-using-numpy-and-pa/46869132?noredirect=1#comment80685736_46869132) that would work if your cells did not contain any special/whitespace characters besides the dots.

```
energy = energy.replace('...', np.nan, regex=False)
```

Comment: I think it should be `energy = energy.replace('...', np.nan, regex=False)`

Comment: @MaxU regex is False by default, meaning there was something wrong with the column values (possibly leading whitespaces), and so I decided to go with regex. Will add yours in as well!

Comment: `energy = energy.replace('...', np.nan)`   Works well